# Вопрос по оперативке

Tags: память

Если у меня в компе стоит 8 гб озу 2 планками по 2400 мгц с таймингами 15-15-15-36, а я еще купил 16 гб озу 2 планками по 2666 мгц и таймингами 15-17-17-35. Вопрос в том что будет если я поставлю их в комп вместе?

Comment: Поставьте, сгореть не должно (если источник потянет). По идее БИОС нынешний должен все настроить. Если не заработает или будет сбоить, то Вы это увидите.

Comment: у меня материнка B360 я думаю что все должно быть хорошо. На сколько я знаю на b360 нельзя ни тайминги ни частоту менять

Comment: Вообще-то это сильно зависит от матери. Но если у неё банки памяти не могут работать на независимой частоте, ставьте более медленную память в нулевой канал.

Comment: По идее, на памяти теперь должны быть микросхемы с информацией о таймингах. И по идее, современные БИОСы должны эту информацию считывать и настраивать контроллер ОЗУ правильно. НО! Далеко не все производители памяти поддерживают эту спецификацию. Ведущие производители поддерживают, а нонеймы не очень. Потом еще не все версии БИОСов корректно читают эту инфу и настраивают контроллер. Потом еще не все контроллеры памяти  корректно работают, если у них разная память в каналах. Если у Вас все срастется, то будет работать. Если где-то не срастется, то увы...

Comment: Ну а так-то, чтобы не мучиться, или если не заработает, то продайте всю старую память и купите 32 гига одной планкой или двумя планками. :-)